# MySQL, get sum of two queries

Tags: mysql, sql, outer-join

I have three different tables about `Product` having different columns and structure, assume

**Product1**, **Product2**, **Product3**

So, I'm trying to get sum of count(*) of three tables having same `user_id`, i.e. foreach user_id field.

**Table - Product1**

```
select P.user_id, count(*) 
from Product1 P  
group by P.user_id
```

**Table - Product2**

```
select P.user_id, count(*) 
from Product2 P  
group by P.user_id
```

**Table - Product3**

```
select P.user_id, count(*) 
from Product3 P  
group by P.user_id
```

They give me `user_id` field and `count(*)`,

Can I add results of count(*), foreach **user_id** field? Thanks, in advance

Comment: _Column_, not field. Consider `UNION ALL`.

Comment: What does "while having [the] same user_id [field]" mean? Please edit your question to be clear. Use enough words & sentences to say what you mean. Also please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Thanks, @philipxy. I did some changes to make it more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having three tables with the same structure is usually a sign of poor database design.  You should figure out ways to combine the tables into a single table.

In any case, you can aggregate the results.  One way is:

```
select user_id, sum(cnt)
from ((select user_id, count(*) as cnt
       from product1
       group by user_id
      ) union all
      (select user_id, count(*) as cnt
       from product2
       group by user_id
      ) union all
      (select user_id, count(*) as cnt
       from product3
       group by user_id
      )
     ) up
group by user_id;
```

You want to use `union all` rather than a `join` because MySQL does not support `full outer join`.  `Union all` ensures that users from all three tables are included.

Aggregating twice (in the subqueries and the outer query) allows MySQL to use indexes for the inner aggregations.  That can be a performance advantage.

Also, if you are looking for a particular user or set of users, use a `where` clause in the subqueries.  That is more efficient (in MySQL) than bringing all the data together in subqueries and then doing the filtering.

Comment: You are right about, table structure. But it was designed because of the need for project and table structures

Answer (score 2):

Combine the results using `UNION` and then do the addition.

**Query**

```
select t.`user_id`, sum(`count`) as `total` from(
    select `user_id`, count(*) as `count`
    from `Product1`
    group by `user_id`
    union all
    select `user_id`, count(*) 
    from `Product2` 
    group by `user_id`
    union all
    select `user_id`, count(*) 
    from `Product3`
    group by `user_id`
) t
group by t.`user_id`;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could sum the result of union all

```
select user_id, sum(my_count)
from (

select P.user_id, count(*)  my_count
from Product1 P  
group by P.user_id
UNION ALL
select P.user_id, count(*) 
from Product2 P  
group by P.user_id
UNION ALL 
select P.user_id, count(*) 
from Product3 P  
group by P.user_id ) t
group by user_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can :)

```
SELECT SUM(userProducts) userProducts 
FROM (
    SELECT count(user_id) userProducts FROM Product1 WHERE user_id = your_user_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT count(user_id) userProducts FROM Product2 WHERE user_id = your_user_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT count(user_id) userProducts FROM Product3 WHERE user_id = your_user_id
) s
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below. Not tried in db so could get syntax error.

select p.user_id ,sum(total) from (
select P.user_id, count(*) total from product1 p group by P.user_id
union all
select P.user_id, count(*) total from product2 p group by P.user_id
union all
select P.user_id, count(*) total from product3 p group by P.user_id
) a

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can aggregate results from different `tables` using `join` and `union` based on our requirement. In your case Union All will work perfectly and can write optimised query by using `count(1)` instead of `count(*)`, as it uses first Index of the `table` which is more often clustered Index.

```
select user_id, sum(cnt)
from ((select user_id, count(1) as cnt
       from product1
       group by user_id
      ) union all
      (select user_id, count(1) as cnt
       from product2
       group by user_id
      ) union all
      (select user_id, count(1) as cnt
       from product3
       group by user_id
      )
     ) a
group by user_id;
```